# Filter questions by "has answer"?

Tags: support, status-completed, search

Today I was searching through tags related to `rasterization` and wanted to filter by questions that have an answer. I couldn't find an easy way to do this. See the screenshot below:

[image]

On the left you can easily filter by: No answers, No accepted answer, Has bounty

but there is no filter for "answered,"with accepted answer".

Is there a way to filter/search SE for those with answers?

Comment: I've removed the [meta-tag:feature-request] from here because for that you would need to ask at [meta.se] (where it may or may not have already been requested).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure about how to do it with the filter, but using the search box you can do the following:

1. for questions that have answers posted (even if none are accepted)

   ```
   [rasterization] answers:1
   ```

   this will return results that have at least 1 answer.  You can change the number to find questions that have more answers too if you wish.
2. for questions that have an *accepted* answer

   ```
   [rasterization] isanswered:yes
   ```

   This will find questions that have an accepted answer (so therefore at least one answer).  Note that this one gives the accepted answer as the search result, not the question, but clicking on it will take you to the full Q&A.

When you start typing into the search box at the top of the screen you will see it offers search tips that help refine your search results.

---

3. A bit of a deeper look at the advanced search options reveals also

   ```
   [rasterization] hasaccepted:yes
   ```

   This will return Questions that have an accepted answer.  You can also combine these with the other advanced search options.

If you click on "Advanced Search Tips" when you've made your search you'll be given a list of all of these

> ```
> Search type   Search syntax
> Tags          [tag]
> Exact         "words here"
> Author        user:1234
>               user:me (yours)
> Score         score:3 (3+)
>               score:0 (none)
> Answers       answers:3 (3+)
>               answers:0 (none)
>               isaccepted:yes
>               hasaccepted:no
>               inquestion:1234
> Views         views:250
> Sections      title:apples
>               body:"apples oranges"
> URL           url:"*.example.com"
> Favorites     infavorites:mine
>               infavorites:1234
> Status        closed:yes
>               duplicate:no
>               migrated:no
>               wiki:no
>               deleted:no
> Types         is:question
>               is:answer
> Exclude       -[tag]
>               -apples
> ```

And a link to [How do I search?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, follow-up question: is it possible to add this feature so it is more accessible (e.g. shown along with other filters?)

Comment: @GISKid That would be a question for [Meta.se] Stack Exchange.  But I think you're looking at the wrong place.  I think people looking for **Answers** would be using a search (where these advanced search tips are found), whereas filters are used for people coming back every day looking for questions to answer themselves, so they're looking for unanswered questions.  Filters are saved searches for people coming back every day, and in my view people don't come back every day looking for the same answered questions

Comment: Thanks! That explanation makes sense to me. Typically, that is my workflow as well, looking to answer unanswered questions 95% of the time. This was the first time I was using the search to look for answers given a specific tag!